# Objective C, C++, Including two files with the same class name

Tags: objective-c, include, objective-c++

I have an Objective C Class called Donald, I also have a C++ class called Donald in a static library that I would like to use in the same project. They both have a header file called Donald.h. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include both header files by specifying a bit more of the path e.g.

```
#import "staticlibraryheaders/Donald.h"
#import "Donald.h"
```

However, you might find that the code won't compile since you are declaring two types both called Donald.  If the compiler sees:

```
Donald* duck;
```

How does it know to type duck as a pointer to an instance of the C++ class or the Objective-C class?  You might be able to fix that if the C++ class is in a C++ namespace.  However, that hits the limit of my C++ knowledge.

Comment: with a namespace and qualifying the include file with a path this include is possible. However I ended up changing the names in the static library cause it was a bit of a hassle.